# SSHing thru an HTTP proxy

Tags: linux, ssh, http, http-proxy

Typical scenario: I'm trying to SSH thru a corporate HTTP proxy to a remote machine using corkscrew, and I get:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Obviously, there's a lot of reasons this might be happening - the proxy might not allow this, the remote box might not be running sshd, etc.

So, I tried to tunnel manually via telnet:

```
$ telnet proxy.evilcorporation.com 82
Trying XX.XX.XX.XX...
Connected to proxy.evilcorporation.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
CONNECT myremotehost.com:22 HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
```

So, unless I'm mistaken... it looks like the connection is *working*.

So, why then, doesn't it work via corkscrew?

```
ssh -vvv root@myremotehost.com -p 22 -o "ProxyCommand corkscrew proxy.evilcorporation.com 82 myremotehost.com 22"
OpenSSH_6.6, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec corkscrew proxy.evilcorporation.com 82 myremotehost.com 22
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: You've established a connection on port 22 via CONNECT, but have you actually tried an SSH handshake through it? Perhaps the proxy detects SSH, which is easy, and drops the connection.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are trying to tunnel through a proxy against which *corkscrew* has not been designed/tested/debugged. [Corkscrew's home page](http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/) states (verbatim):

> Corkscrew has been tested with the following HTTP proxies :
>
> Gauntlet
>
> CacheFlow
>
> JunkBuster
>
> Squid
>
> Apache's mod_proxy
>
> Please email me if you get it to work with another proxy

Do you know which proxy is run, in your case?

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether corkscrew is working correctly by running your proxycommand directly on the commandline. In your case, running

```
corkscrew proxy.evilcorporation.com 82 myremotehost.com 22
```

should produce output like

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7
```

I.e. the SSH protocol banner from the remote server. If this doesn't work, then something is wrong with your proxy and/or your ssh server.